# Digitally Signed Soap Headers using digital certificate - Apache CXF Client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I am writing an Apache CXF Client and I need some assistance.

Can someone please cast some light on how to digitally sign soap headers using a digital certificate for creating Apache CXF Clients?

I am consuming webServices where I want to sign the headers.

Or let me know any better solution to digitally sign headers in an Apache CXF Client.